# Infopath Regex for 7 - 15 characters with atleast one digit and character

Tags: infopath, infopath-rules, regex

I am trying to create a textbox in infoth form with following creteria:
1.) Length should be 7-15 characters
2.) It should contain at least one digit
3.) It should contain at least one character
4.) It should contain only digits and alphabets

[a-zA-Z1-9 ]{7,15} give seven to 15 characters alphanumeric but does not confirm that at one digit and alphabet.

I tried to add some like ^\d*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$ but no luck.

Than i trid to add "[a-zA-Z1-9 ]{7,15}" and "/d" in or condition but still not working.

Could someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the limited support for RegEx in InfoPath you'll not be able to do the verification in a single RegEx but you can do it by adding this validation rule:

```
FieldName | does not math pattern | [a-zA-Z\d]{7,15} | or
FieldName | does not math pattern | .*\d.*           | or
FieldName | does not math pattern | .*[a-zA-Z].*     |
```

If InfoPath had had full support for RegEx including lookaheads then the regex could have been `^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])[a-zA-Z\d]{7,15}$`, but even then the above is probably a little easier for many to understand

Comment: Thanks! it worked like charm. Is it possible that this field could be left blank. I mean either it could be left blank or it should match the pattern.

Comment: If your field has "Cannot be blank" unchecked then the field can either be blank or it has to validate. (The advanced regex doesn't allow blank but could easily be modified to do that)

Comment: Perfect. you saved my buts :)

Answer (score 0):

I always struggle with regex its the language of freaks! I tend to use an online testbed, I've found [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/) to be excellent.